# Setting the viminfo path in gVim for portability (Windows)

Tags: vim, gvim, portable, vimrc

I'm trying to make my gVim installation as portable as possible, and in doing so I want to put the `_viminfo` file in the `$VIM` directory rather than `$HOME`. I'm pretty new to hacking vimrc configurations, but here's what I've been trying:

```
let viminfopath=$VIM."\\_viminfo"
execute "set viminfo='1000,n".escape(viminfopath, ' ')

" Some other portability stuff.
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
if has("win32") || has("win64")
    set directory=$TMP
else
    set directory=~/tmp
end
```

This doesn't seem to be working, though; does anyone have any tips?

Thanks!

**Edit:** running `:echo viminfopath` gives the result `F:\Programs\Vim\_viminfo`, so the path itself is valid at least. It must be the `execute` operation that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [amix's suggestions](http://amix.dk/blog/post/162): (I know the `MySys` approach can be done in different and better ways, but I think you can get the idea)

```
fun! MySys()
  return "windows"
endfun

set runtimepath=~/vim_local,$VIMRUNTIME
source ~/vim_local/vimrc
```

[$VIMRUNTIME](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'runtimepath') is the approach here, really interesting. Check [amix's vimrc](http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.txt) as well, there are some cross-plataform tips to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that if you use a backslash as your directory separator, you're going to break anything that isn't Windows.

```
let viminfopath=$VIM."\\_viminfo"
```

I would shoot for

```
let viminfopath=$VIM."/_viminfo"
```

instead. That should work in Windows as well as anything else.

Granted, that's a guess, but it's where I'd start.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work. Thanks though. – Will Vousden Mar 23 '10 at 19:00   (This comment was from a deleted exact duplicate of this answer.)